# ASP.Net MVC, ViewPage<Dynamic> and EditorFor/LabelFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic

I'm playing with MVC3 using the Razer syntax, though I believe the problem to be more general.

In the controller, I have something like:

```
ViewModel.User = New User(); // The model I want to display/edit
ViewModel.SomeOtherProperty = someOtherValue; // Hense why need dynamic
Return View();
```

My View inherits from System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage

But if I try to do something like:

```
<p>
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.User.Name
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.User.Name
</p>
```

I get the error: "An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation"

However, the use of ViewPage seems quite common, as are EditorFor/LabelFor. Therefore I'd be surprised if there's not a way to do this - appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the expression trees => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx must not contain any dynamic variables.

Unfortunately this is the case for TModel when you use dynamics in it.

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func> expression
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `ViewPage<Dynamic>`. I would recommend you using a view model and strongly type your view to this view model:

```
var model = new MyViewModel
{
    User = new User
    {
        Name = "foo"
    },
    SomeOtherProperty = "bar"
};
return View(model);
```

and then strongly type your view to `ViewPage<MyViewModel>` and:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.User.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.User.Name)
<div>@Model.SomeOtherProperty</div>
```

Comment: In order to type your view, add a @model Namespace.Classname declaration to the top of your cshtml file.